# Reading a CSV file that is hosted online using JS

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have been searching for almost 2 hours to find a way to read a csv file that is hosted online. My data is hosted [here](http://bahadorsaket.com/others/ranking.csv).

I came across a library called [papa parse](https://www.papaparse.com/). It apparently allows me to do that. I have the following code

```
   Papa.parse("http://bahadorsaket.com/others/ranking.csv", {
        download: true,
        complete: function(results) {
             console.log("Finished:", results.data);
        }
   })
```

It returns me following error: *

> No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access.

I was wondering if I am doing something wrong. OR there is a different way to load a csv file that is hosted online.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There is chrome extension which can resolve this CORS error

Link : 
https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allow-control-allow-origi/nlfbmbojpeacfghkpbjhddihlkkiljbi?hl=en

Also you can start the chrome with below line which can also resolve it

chrome.exe --disable-web-security

This is for windows btw

Hope this helps

Comment: Please DO NOT DO THIS. This opens up your computer to all kinds of really bad security stuff in normal every-day browsing.

Answer (score 0):

It is not that you are doing anything wrong, its that the remote URL doesnt allow cors and your browser will deny any traffic to remote origins.  The safer option would be for you to make that call server side to get the csv and have papa.parse call a local endpoint.